# How to get the index of an element of a std::vector from the reference to one of it's items?

Tags: c++, stdvector

How would you *elegantly* (and in a modern C++ way) write a function that returns the index of a vector element, taking as argument this vector, and a reference to one of its elements ?

Exceptions handling would be appreciated.

```
#include <vector>

template <class T>
std::size_t GetIndexFromRef(std::vector<T> &vec, T &item)
{
...
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
template <class T>
std::size_t GetIndexFromRef(std::vector<T> const &vec, T const &item)
{
    T const *data = vec.data();

    if(std::less<T const *>{}(&item, data) || std::greater_equal<T const *>{}(&item, data + vec.size()))
        throw std::out_of_range{"The given object is not part of the vector."};
    
    return static_cast<std::size_t>(&item - vec.data());
};
```

I'm using `std::less` and `std::greater_equal`, because ([[comparisons.general§2]](http://eel.is/c++draft/comparisons#general-2)):

> For templates `less`, `greater`, `less_­equal`, and `greater_­equal`, the specializations for any pointer type yield a result consistent with the implementation-defined strict total order over pointers ([defns.order.ptr]).
> [*Note 1*: If `a < b` is well-defined for pointers `a` and `b` of type `P`, then `(a < b) == less<P>()(a, b)`, `(a > b) == greater<P>()(a, b)`, and so forth.
> — *end note*]

Otherwise, performing the comparison with an object that isn't part of the vector would be UB.

Comment: thanks ! it was indeed a typo, the vector is passed by reference